# Android Landscape/Portrait changing difficults

Tags: android, view

Target:

If I'm switching ffrom a Portrait to a Landscape the complete layout should change (same buttons, same textfields, but different positions). Until now the problem is that they lose the values.

I've set

```
  <application ...
...android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" ...>
```

2 different Layouts in:

```
    +Layout
    +-main.xml
    +-second.xml
    +Layout-land
    +-second.xml
```

ex: I switch from a portrait to a landscape, I want to save all the portrait values (buttons, textfields) and restore them in the landscape view.

Now I'm missing some input for the method in MyActivity()

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 // how should i handle this?
}
```

I've found hints like setContentView(...) and "handle this Problem in the Manifest file". Maybe my approach to this is completely false. I would appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Just let android handle the orientation changes?

You got the xml-files right: Two different layouts with the same name in the two folders layout/ and layout-land/

Just don't set

```
 <application ... 
...android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" ...>
```

and Android will handle everything for you :)

Cheers
Ali3n